# Turn off USB of a port and leave power on while no device attached

Tags: usb

I want to turn off (and back on) the USB functionality of a port while leaving the power for charging purpose. 
I can do this easily with *unbind* and *bind* once a device is connected.
However, is there a way to do it before a device is connected, to never have a device going active in the first place?
I only want to have this one USB port active (manually activated from the console) for service purpose.

I'm using RPi3 ComputeModule with Raspbian Stretch.

Thanks
McL

Comment: What model RPi, and which OS version?

Comment: RPi 3 Compute Module and Raspbian Stretch.

Answer (score 1):

You can let the devices bind on plugin and then unbind them right away via an `udev` rule. I haven't tested those but they should get you started:

```
SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", RUN+="/bin/sh -c 'echo -n %k > /sys/bus/usb/drivers/usb/unbind'"
SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", RUN+="/bin/sh -c 'echo 0 > /sys/bus/usb/devices/%k/authorized'"
```

You can disable this rule from the console before using the USB ports should you need them.

Answer (score 0):

You can call `unbind` on the internal USB hub driver itself.  Output from `lsusb` should include:

```
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0424:9514 Standard Microsystems Corp. SMC9514 Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

There are directories with `bind` and `unbind` nodes for them in `/sys/bus/usb/drivers`:

```
hub/
smsc95xx/
```

Comment: Ok, thanks. But, that will turn off all USB ports, correct?
Is there no way to selectively turn off ports? I have a Audio CODEC on one USB port and a storage media on another one, both of them I need permanently. 
It's an (1) external port that I want to disable but keep supply on for charging.

Comment: Yeah, that will turn off all ports.  I very much doubt there is a way to turn off an individual port.  You could use a small external hub for the stuff you want to disable.

Comment: Actually, there would be a way, if we would have equipped the EEPROM to the LAN9514. Unfortunately, we didn't.

Comment: As a 'second best' solution, it would also be ok to turn the supply off, i.e. completely shut the port down. However, this also seems possible only once a device on the port has been enumerated.

Comment: Output from `lsusb` on my RPi3B+ lists: Bus 001 Device 007: ID 0781:556c SanDisk Corp. Ultra
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0424:7800 Standard Microsystems Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0424:2514 Standard Microsystems Corp. USB 2.0 Hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0424:2514 Standard Microsystems Corp. USB 2.0 Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub                   It's not obvious which of the driver folders it is necessary to `unbind`... how is that determined?